# devexpress mvc datagrid edit popup menu inside texbox width and height?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, datagrid, devexpress, devextreme

How can I change textbox height and width in a popup on devexpress mvc datagrid? I am using

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid().Columns(c => {
    c.Add().DataField("MyField").Visible(true).AllowGrouping(true);
}
```

I tried `c.Add().DataField("Myfield").Width(100)` but it is only working in datagrid; it does not work in popup element

Comment: I tried c.Add().DataField("Myfield").Width(100) but it is working only in datagrid. it does not work in popup element

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to know that you are treating with a [Form](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxForm/) and not with a simple grid, so you basically have to configure the form [EditorOptions](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Form/CustomizeItem/Mvc/Light/)

So in jQuery it would be like this

```
$("#datagrid").dxDataGrid({        ,
    "editing": {
        "form": { items: [{dataField:"yourField",editorOptions:"width:100%"}]}
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is a little old and doesn't work now so I'll give an updated answer.

This would change the width for a field in the popup form:

```
$("#datagrid").dxDataGrid({        ,
        "editing": {
        "form": { 
                  items: [{
                      dataField:"yourField",
                      editorOptions: {
                                  width: "100%"
                       }
                  ]}
    }
});
```

Also if you wanted to have more control and use groups and set things, like height, you could use:

```
 $("#datagrid").dxDataGrid({ 
editing: {
            mode: "popup",
            allowUpdating: true,
            popup: {
                showTitle: true,
                title: "Message",
                labelLocation: "top"
            },
            form: {
                items: [
                    {
                        itemType: "group",
                        caption: "My Fields",
                        items: [
                            {
                                dataField: "Field1",
                                editorOptions: {
                                    height: 200
                                    }
                             },
                            {
                                dataField: "Field2",
                                editorOptions: {
                                    value: true
                                }
                            }

                        ]
                    }, {
                        itemType: "group",
                        caption: "My other fields",
                        items: [
                            { 
                              dataField: "field3", 
                              helpText: "Example: +1(111)111-1111" 
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
});
```

Notice that with and without grouping both use the editorOptions to control each field.